# listing visits in last 24 hours

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, asp-classic

I am trying to list last visits per hour in last 24 hours. I thought the following code would do it, but I get the outcome below. Any idea where I screwed it up?

[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],[,0],

```
Dim ListHours()
HoursInCurrentDay = "24"
Redim ListHours(HoursInCurrentDay)
For Days = 0 To 23
    ListHours(Hours) = Hours
Next
SQLARR2 = ListHours
For x = 1 to ubound(SQLARR2)
    SQL = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT VISITORIP) AS TOTALVISITS"
    SQL = SQL & " FROM STATS"
    SQL = SQL & " WHERE DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()) = '"& SQLARR2(x) &"' AND DATEENTERED BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()-1, 101) AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101)"
    Set objVisits = objConn.Execute(SQL)    

    If objVisits.EOF Then
    Else 

    List = List + "[" & SQLARR2(x) & "," & objVisits("TOTALVISITS") & "],"

    End If
Next

Response.Write List
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the provided result, I'm noticing that SQLARR2(x) isn't generating a value. All results come up [,0] where the first (missing) element is hour and the second element the count.  I don't think ListHours values are being properly defined as you Hours variable doesn't have an assignment (not within the snippet anyhow.)

If you change

```
For Days = 0 To 23        
   ListHours(Hours) = Hours
Next
```

to

```
For Days = 0 To 23        
   ListHours(Days) = Days
Next
```

the correct hours should be added to your list. This should also fix the query (and the query result) as SQLARR2(x) is used to build the dynamic sql as well.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use a simple query like:

```
SELECT * FROM VISITS WHERE (VISIT.TIME > now - 24hours AND VISIT.TIME < now)
```